# mySQL: Insert meta_key into table when doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, select, insert

Ok I'm looking to run a looped query against in mySQL against a Wordpress database. Certain records have a custom field of [city name] (ex: meta_key = 'sidebar' & meta_value = 'chicago'). The problem is some have this custom field while others don't. I've isolated the records that don't via the following query:

```
SELECT object_id 
FROM wp_term_relationships 
WHERE term_taxonomy_id = (
    SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms 
    WHERE name = 'Chicago') 
  AND object_id > 5911
```

The resulting set of object_id will need to have the

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value,post_id) 
VALUES ('sidebar','chicago',[object_id])
```

So my question is how to combine these so the SELECT loops through to run the INSERT for each object_id that results. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value,post_id)
SELECT 'sidebar','chicago', object_id 
  FROM wp_term_relationships 
 WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 
       (
          SELECT term_id 
            FROM wp_terms 
           WHERE name = 'Chicago'
       ) 
   AND object_id > 5911
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for helping me put the pieces together on this Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Your Solution is here...

```
 import java.sql.*;
   public class sample 
  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

 try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection  c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
    Statement s=c.createStatement();
    Statement dbInsert = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet r=s.executeQuery("SELECT object_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id = (SELECT term_id FROM wp_terms WHERE name = 'Chicago') AND object_id > 5911");
   while(r.next())
   {

      dbInsert.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta (meta_key, meta_value,post_id) VALUES ('sidebar','chicago','"+r.getInt("object_id")+"'");

   }


  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
 }
```